# R stm package error: "vectorized sources must have a positive length entry"

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I think I'm making a pretty simple mistake but I'm a rookie at R and am having a hard time figuring it out. I'm trying to use the 'stm' package in R do some topic-modeling on a dataset of tweets I scraped.

The dataset is formatted in two columns, one with the name of the tweet-sender, with column header "meta" and the other with the vocab of the tweet, column header, "vocab". After running the script below, I get the following errors:

```
Error: is.Source(s) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In is.Source(s) : vectorized sources must have a positive length entry

library(stm)
library(igraph)
setwd("c:/Users/Adam/Desktop/RTwitter")

data <-read.csv("TweetDataSTM.csv")
processed <- textProcessor(data$documents, metadata = data)
out <- prepDocuments(processed$documents, processed$vocab, processed$meta)
docs <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <-out$meta

> library(stm)
> library(igraph)
> setwd("c:/Users/Adam/Desktop/RTwitter")
> 
> rm(list=ls())
> 
> data <-read.csv("TweetDataSTM.csv")
> processed <- textProcessor(data$documents, metadata = data)
Building corpus... 
Error: is.Source(s) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In is.Source(s) : vectorized sources must have a positive length entry
> out <- prepDocuments(processed$documents, processed$vocab, processed$meta)
Error in prepDocuments(processed$documents, processed$vocab, processed$meta) : 
  object 'processed' not found
> docs <- out$documents
Error: object 'out' not found
> vocab <- out$vocab
Error: object 'out' not found
> meta <-out$meta
Error: object 'out' not found
```

(any advice would be greatly appreciated!)

-Adam

Comment: First run it line by line and find out where exactly the error occurs. It could be that your data isn't actually being read in for some reason. Edit your question to include a sample of the data.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake occurs because your columns are named `vocab` and `meta`. But here

> processed <- textProcessor(data$documents, metadata = data)

you are trying to call a column `documents` that - as far as I see - does not exist in your data.frame. Try changing the code to:

```
processed <- textProcessor(data$vocab, metadata = data)
```